Is Brownian motion an almost-sure homotopy?
Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined on the filtered probability space
$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t), \mathbb{P})$. Then, all of the sample paths of $B$ start at the origin, and all of the paths are continuous.
We might ask if $B$ describes a homotopy from $B_t$ to the constant map $B_0 = \mathbf{0}$, with both considered as maps $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$.
The issue with this is that there is not necessarily any topology on $\Omega$.
Question: Given a pair $(B, \Omega)$ of Brownian motion and associated filtered probability space, for any $\Omega’ \subseteq \Omega$, define a topology on $\Omega’$ by the coarsest topology which makes $B$ continuous as a homotopy $\Omega \times [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2$.
Does there exist a pair $(W, \Pi)$ such that the topology on $\Pi’$ does not have isolated points, for some $\Pi’ \subseteq \Pi$ with $\mathbb{Q}(\Pi’) = 1$?
Feel free to suggest improvements to the question. I am essentially wondering if there is any reasonable way to interpret Brownian motion as a homotopy. It is entirely speculative.
